# How to cancel UIScrollView scrolling outside triangle shape UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIView which is triangle shape. Then i add UIScrollView(name A) with imageview into UIView. There is also one UIScrollView(name B) at background.

Below is the image.
[image]

My problem is that when i touch or scroll outside the triangle shape of UIView, the scrollView (A) starts scrolling. I want to scroll B there.
Then how can i stop scrolling of UIScrollView (A)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a subclass of UIScrollView for scroll view A
2. Override [pointInside:withEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:)
3. Return `NO` if point is outside of triangle shape, otherwise return `YES`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved to find touches outside the path. But still touches happen to top scrollview A. How can i pass that touch to B? So that scrollview B will scroll.

Comment: Have you another views between A and B?

Comment: No but the top scrollview A covers whole screen.

Comment: scroll view B must have UIScrollView class, not your subclass

Comment: Yes i already have. B is the background scollview with 320*480 and A is the top scrollview with trianlge bazier path which is also have size 320*480. I think i should pass touch to scrollview B. But i don't know how to pass?

Comment: created new repo for you,  take a look https://github.com/VladimirKravchenko/VKTransparentScrollView